# How to get row count and total sum of fields value through XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a file format requirement as following where I need to get row count and total sum of the field. In the example there are three rows with the column that has amount values and in the fourth row, i would need total row count and sum of the amounts to be populated.

```
Alex, Scot              10091978       90.00
Brad, Ander             23061976       40.00
Rodney, Philips         04091983       35.00
03 165.00
```

**XML Input**

```
 <wd:Report_Data 
 xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT001_Test_Reward_Report">
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Employee_ID>12344</wd:Employee_ID>
 <wd:dateOfBirth>1975-05-06</wd:dateOfBirth>
 <wd:lastName>Alex</wd:lastName>
 <wd:firstName>Scot</wd:firstName>
 <wd:Pay_Frequency>M1</wd:Pay_Frequency>
 </wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payment_Date>2019-04-02</wd:Payment_Date>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 <wd:Result_Line_Amount>40</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Employee_ID>12355</wd:Employee_ID>
 <wd:dateOfBirth>1958-05-06</wd:dateOfBirth>
 <wd:lastName>Hyrus</wd:lastName>
 <wd:firstName>Marike</wd:firstName>
 <wd:Pay_Frequency>M1</wd:Pay_Frequency>
 </wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payment_Date>2019-04-04</wd:Payment_Date>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 <wd:Result_Line_Amount>10</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Employee_ID>12366</wd:Employee_ID>
 <wd:dateOfBirth>1986-09-10</wd:dateOfBirth>
 <wd:lastName>Elite</wd:lastName>
 <wd:firstName>Samsung</wd:firstName>
 <wd:Pay_Frequency>M1</wd:Pay_Frequency>
 </wd:Worker_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payment_Date>2019-04-02</wd:Payment_Date>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_group>
 <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 <wd:Result_Line_Amount>30</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
 </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 </wd:Report_Data>

   XSLT I have tried so far

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT001_Test_Reward_Report"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs this">

<!--**************************************************************************************-->
<!--    Date           XSLT Attachment Design                                             -->
<!--    06-17-2019     Transformation to transform file format from xml to .txt(fixed )   -->
<!--**************************************************************************************-->
<!--    06-17-2019     Initial Version                                                    -->
<!--**************************************************************************************-->

<!--The final output file will be text formatted with an encoding of *NA*-->
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text" use-character-maps="custom-char-filter" />

<!--declare global variables here such as delimiter and linefeed-->
    <xsl:variable name="vDelimiter" select="''"/>
<xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed2" select="'
    '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vWrapQuotes" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateFormat" select="'[Y0001][M01][D01]'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateTimeFormat" select="'[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pDateValue" select="current-date()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SumAmount" select="0"/>
     <xsl:variable name="i" select="0"/>

<!--Root Template-->
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">

    <!--declare root variables here such as current datetime or other repeating values-->


    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:formatDate($pDateValue))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

    <!--Process detail records-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry" />

    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SumAmount"/>

</xsl:template>

<!--Detail Record Template-->
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">

    <!--
    Detail Record


    -->

    <!--Record Type - -->
    <xsl:text>D</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth(wd:Worker_group/wd:Employee_ID, ' ', 8, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth((this:formatDate(wd:Worker_group/wd:dateOfBirth)), ' ', 8, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth(wd:Worker_group/wd:lastName, ' ', 40,'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth(wd:Worker_group/wd:firstName, ' ', 40, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth(wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group/wd:Result_Line_Amount, ' ', 9, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth(wd:Worker_group/wd:Pay_Frequency, ' ', 2, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:fixedWidth((this:formatDate(wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:Payment_Date)), ' ', 8, 'left'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="Amount" select="this:setOutput(wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group/wd:Result_Line_Amount)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Amount"/>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SumAmount" select="$SumAmount + $Amount"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />     

    </xsl:template>
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <!--This function returns the input value followed by a delmiter                                  -->
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <xsl:function name="this:setOutput">
    <xsl:param name="value" />

    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput($value,false())"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <!--This function returns the input value followed by a delmiter                                  -->
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <xsl:function name="this:setOutput">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="finalValue" as="xs:boolean"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vWrappedValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="if($vWrapQuotes = false()) then $value else this:wrapQuotes($value)"/>            
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="if ($finalValue = false()) then concat(string($vWrappedValue),$vDelimiter) else $vWrappedValue"/>

    </xsl:function>

    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <!--This function is designed to wrap a string in quotes if required                              -->
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->  
    <xsl:function name="this:wrapQuotes">
    <xsl:param name="field"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($field,'&quot;','&quot;&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <!--This function is designed to pad a string to the left or right to a fixed number of characters-->
    <!--    str: a string input                                                                       -->
    <!--    chr: a character used for padding                                                         -->
    <!--    len: a number of defining the total length of the output                                  -->
    <!--    dir: the direction of the alignment default is left; right if specified)                  -->
    <!--         Note: if something is aligned left it will be padded on the right and vice versa     --> 
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <xsl:function name="this:padString">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:param name="chr" />
    <xsl:param name="len" />
    <xsl:param name="dir" />

    <xsl:variable name="padLength">
        <xsl:value-of select="$len - string-length($str)" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="pad">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $padLength">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chr" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="if ($dir = 'right') then concat($str,$pad) else concat($pad,$str)" />

    </xsl:function>

    <!--********************************************************************************************    -->
    <!--This function is designed to align a string to the left or right to a fixed number of characters-->
    <!--    str: a string input                                                                         -->
    <!--    chr: a character used for padding                                                           -->
    <!--    len: a number of defining the total length of the output                                    -->
    <!--    dir: the direction of the alignment default is left; right if specified)                    -->
    <!--         Note: if something is aligned left it will be padded on the right and vice versa       -->    
    <!--********************************************************************************************    -->
    <xsl:function name="this:fixedWidth">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:param name="chr" />
    <xsl:param name="len" />
    <xsl:param name="dir" />        

    <xsl:variable name="padLength">
        <xsl:value-of select="$len - string-length($str)" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="pad">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $padLength">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chr" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="if ($dir = 'right') then substring(concat($pad,$str),1,$len) else substring(concat($str,$pad),1,$len)" />

    </xsl:function>

    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->
    <!--This function can be modified as needed for the appropriate date format                       -->
    <!--********************************************************************************************  -->    
    <xsl:function name="this:formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="pDateValue" />

    <xsl:value-of select="if (xs:string($pDateValue) = '') then '' else format-date(xs:date($pDateValue), $vDateFormat)" />

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="this:formatDateTime">
    <xsl:param name="pDateTimeValue" />

    <xsl:value-of select="if ($pDateTimeValue = '') then '' else format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($pDateTimeValue),$vDateTimeFormat )" />
    </xsl:function>

<!--*************************************************************************************************  -->
<!--Character Maps can be used to replace special and/or foreign characters where appropriate          -->
<!--The big avantage is that these don't have to be called explicitly, the processor will handle this  -->
<!--while writing the output.                                                                          -->
<!--*************************************************************************************************  -->
<xsl:character-map name="custom-char-filter">

    <xsl:output-character character="*" string="" />
    <xsl:output-character character=":" string="" />
    <xsl:output-character character="^" string="" />
    <xsl:output-character character="~" string="" />
</xsl:character-map>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have also tried with few xslt functions (Total count, total row count), 
     but nothing seems working.

Thanks,
  Jithendra.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your input XML, along with any XSLT you have tried please? Thank you!

Comment: Please show an input XML document and the XSLT stylesheet you have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Please show a complete XML with 3 entries, as shown in your expected output. -- Also consider minimizing the XSLT shown - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT001_Test_Reward_Report">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:lastName>Alex</wd:lastName>
            <wd:firstName>Scot</wd:firstName>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
            <wd:Result_Line_Amount>90</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
        </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:lastName>Brad</wd:lastName>
            <wd:firstName>Ander</wd:firstName>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
            <wd:Result_Line_Amount>40</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
        </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:lastName>Rodney</wd:lastName>
            <wd:firstName>Philips</wd:firstName>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
            <wd:Result_Line_Amount>35</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
        </wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT001_Test_Reward_Report">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <!-- records -->
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:lastName"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_group/wd:firstName"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group/wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- summary -->
    <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payroll_Result_Line_group/wd:Result_Line_Amount)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
Alex, Scot  90
Brad, Ander 40
Rodney, Philips 35
3   165
```

Comment: michael, thanks for your inputs. I think this is working but all the output is populating in single row, but it should be in three rows and fourth row should be row count and sum of values.

Comment: That is not what I see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9W. Perhaps you need to change the row separator from `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` (LF) to `<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>` (CRLF)?

Comment: yeah i have added line feed Michael, seems it is working as needed. Thanks for your inputs which got squared the output needed for me.